# Visual Studio 2019 (not VS Code) typescript debugging breakpoint unbound

Tags: typescript, debugging, visual-studio-2019, breakpoints, visual-studio-debugging

What am I Missing .....

I've got an Angular 12 project hosted within a .Net 5 project using Visual Studio 2019 (it is an older application I'm trying to do a quick upgrade of versions on - I know this probably isn't the ideal setup).

I am trying to debug my angular (typescript) components by setting a breakpoint in Visual Studio but I'm getting the 'breakpoint unbound' issue and it's not being hit.  I understand the workings about typescript files getting converted to javascript files for hosting, however, I used to be able to just set a breakpoint in Visual Studio in my typescript files and it would be hit without any issues (Angular 5 with .Net2.2).

I've been googling for ages but can't seem to find exactly what I need to do - possibly it's a tsconfig.json setting or possibly it's that I'm doing a production build with my 'ng build' command for the angular application or maybe theres a development setting I haven't got correct (I'm not sure).

I've found some instructions on how I can debug the code using the Browser but this isn't ideal - it kind of defeats one of the purposes of using a quality IDE.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me - I'm going mad with this!

My tsconfig file content is:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

my tsconfig.app.json file content is:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

and my angular.json file settings are:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "client": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "inlineTemplate": true,
          "inlineStyle": true,
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:class": {
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:directive": {
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:guard": {
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:interceptor": {
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:pipe": {
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:service": {
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "../wwwroot/client",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "none"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "client:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "client:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "client:build"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "client"
}
```

[image: My solution file structure]

Answer (score 1):

Try these and see if one of them works.

1). Go to Tools > Options > Debugging > General > check “Enable JavaScript debugging for ASP .NET(Chrome, Edge and IE)” checkbox. (not sure if this works, you can have a try)

2). Make sure that you have selected “Debug” Mode/Configuration instead of “Release” while debugging.

3). Go to your solution/project folder and delete the `.vs`, `bin` and `obj` folders(you can make a backup), then rebuild your project/solution and debug it.

4).  Try to restart Visual Studio, and reset breakpoints.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Tianyu - unfortunately it didn't work.  

I'm correct in thinking that you should be able to set a breakpoint in a typescript file in Visual Studio within the angular application and it stop when running it in the browser in debug mode??  I used to do it this way with Internet Explorer 11.

Does anyone else have any suggestions or can find a problem in my tsconfig file?

Comment: Yes, VS hit the breakpoint(in TS) and stopped on my side. But I waited for one minutes, or maybe 30 seconds, or two minutes, I don’t remember. And before Debugging process loaded well, I could see that the breakpoints warned similar like “the breakpoints are set but unbound”, I just waited and it worked then.

Comment: Hmm I'm still having trouble to get this working even after a Visual Studio Repair.  I've even tried it with Visual Studio Mac but no joy. I was wondering if you would mind seeing if you can get a breakpoint to hit with my testing solution I've uploaded to GitHub (https://github.com/rasaconsulting-sandy/TestAngularTypescriptDebugging).  I'm suspecting I have a tsconfig / angular.json setting incorrect but can't figure out which one.  I couldn't get a breakpoint to hit with this simple, standard ASP.Net Core Web App with the standard Angular app.  Thanks in advance if you don't mind doing this.

Comment: note: the solution will need the 'nom install' and 'ng build' on the 'client' folder before running in visual studio.

Comment: Hi Sandy, I tested your sample, the breakpoints also didn’t hit on my side. I can confirm that the newly simple created Asp .Net Core project(with Angular) can successfully hit the breakpoints in VS 2019. I checked the tsconfig.json file, angular.json file and other files, and matched them, did some modifications, but I didn’t find or successfully change them to make breakpoints work. I think this should be related to the settings of this project, or the versions of related tools, but need to check more.

Comment: But I’m considering, whether VS 2019 doesn’t support to debug the project(TS files) generated by higher version of Angular CLI.

Comment: Thanks TIanyu - I really appreciate you testing this one for me.  It's good to know that not my computer and Visual Studio install that's the issue here.  I'm also trying to find more information on Angular and Visual Studio support too.